# "Commands out of sync;" Prepared Stored Procedure Error

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli, prepared-statement

I seem to be having some trouble with running a 2nd prepared query after running a 1st prepared stored procedure. I understand this is because I can't buffer results in mySQL, but I'm not sure exactly I should be using to get all the results.

I've tried:

```
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->bind_result($var1, $var2);
    $stmt->free_result();
```

But I still get the same error. The procedure works fine, and is designed to only return 1 row, so not sure.

The full error is:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

UPDATE:

More relevant code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('CALL createNewListing(?,?,?,?,?,?)');

$time = time();
$stmt->bind_param('sdssii', $listing['title'], $listing['price'], $_SESSION['user']['id'], $listing['description'], $time, $listing['featured']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->bind_result($listing['primarypic']['id'], $listing['id']);
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

// Error is generated here.

$statement = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO pictures (listid, primarypic) VALUES (?, ?)');
if (!$statement) {
        echo $mysqli->error;
        die();
}
```

Comment: Can we get the whole snippet minus the query (if it is sensitive)?